# Write a sum formula with VBA in Excel 2007 (=t1+t2+tN)

Tags: vba, excel

In the code below, I catch the double click event on a range of cells named "chrono". If the target cell contains a value, I concatenate it with values already contained in the formula applied to the next cell to the right. I want to obtain something like `=0,1+0,1`, but the cell remains empty.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("chrono")
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cancel = True 'stop the edit mode
    With Target
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = Time
        Else:
            Dim nextCell As Range
            Set nextCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
            If nextCell.Formula = "" Then
                nextCell.Formula = "=" & ((Time - .Value) * 24 * 60 * 60)
            Else:
                nextCell.Formula = nextCell.Formula & "+" & ((Time - .Value) * 24 * 60 * 60)
            End If
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

### Edit

I'm sorry to be unclear, my english is not so good. I want to calculate elapsed time between two double-clicks (so there is no existing data). I'm able to achieve this task doing this:

```
nextCell.Value = Time - .Value
```

Moreover, I'm able to sum multiple inputs doing this:

```
If nextCell.Value = "" Then
    nextCell.Value = Time - .Value
Else:
    nextCell.Value = nextCell.Value + Time - .Value
```

The problem is that every new input overrites `nextCell.Value` while I want to keep track of every single input. I have tried to use a formula (`=t1+t2`) as exposed in the first code sample but double-clicking produces no result.

---

### Edit

I'm trying to build a stopwatch. My goal is to calculate time spent on a task. To make things even more clear, here is what I'm trying to do, step by step:

1. two cells : A1 and B1
2. double-click on A1
3. A1 value: current time
4. double-click on A1
5. B1 formula: "=" & (current time - A1 value)
6. A1 value: empty
7. repeat 2, 3, 4
8. B1 formula: B1 formula & "+" & (current time - A1 value)
9. repeat 2, 3, 4
10. and so on...

Comment: so what's the input and what's the expected output?

Comment: I'm with Larry. It's unclear what you have in place, and then desire once to have post code.

Comment: The code above is ready to use:
1. open a new worksheet in Excel
2. copy/paste my code in the code of this new worksheet
3. create a range named "chrono"
4. double click on any cell included in this range.

Comment: Your code runs fine. It isn't clear what existing data do you have (and in what format - time or other), and what do you want to achieve by the code?

Comment: your code is working with for me, it shows the escaped seconds in the cell to the right of it. The seconds escaped is accumulated result. Maybe it's just a formatting issue? you can set the cell format to `general`?

Comment: Thx @Larry! After reading your confirmation, I finally figured out that the problem came from the specific language with which I'm working. I simply replaced `Formula` with `FormulaLocal`, and now it works! Many thanks to everyone :)

Comment: You may want to answer your own question down below to help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that the problem came from the specific language with which I'm working. I simply replaced `Formula` with `FormulaLocal` and now it works! As an extra, `(Time - .Value) * 1` allows to convert elapsed time to the corresponding decimal value. Many thanks to everyone :)

Comment: All great things are indeed simple)

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel are stored internally as number of days since 1/1/1900.
Therefore 1 day = 1.
Therefore 1 hour = 1/24.
So to have your time in decimal seconds, multiply it by 24 * 60 * 60

---

Edit:
i would refer to `nextCell.Value` instead of `nextCell.Formula` when you refer to the value of the cell, like in `nextCell.Formula = nextCell.Formula & "+" & (Time - .Value)`

Comment: Thanks! Now the dialog box displays the expected output. However, I have one more problem to solve. The code is supposed to display the result in the next cell on the right but nothing happens. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I have just tested `nextCell.Formula = nextCell.Value & "+" & (Time - .Value)` with the same result. I'm sorry but I'm afraid of not having understood your idea.

Comment: I would be greatful if you could take a look at my edited question :)

Answer (score 1):

It still is hard to understand what you're after, but here's a try...

The following version sets a base time with each following double click shows the accumulated time since then.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("chrono")
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cancel = True 'stop the edit mode
    With Target
        Dim nextCell As Range
        Set nextCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        If .Value = "" Then
            nextCell.Formula = ""
            .Value = Time
        Else:
            If nextCell.Formula = "" Then
                nextCell.Formula = "=" & Round((Time - .Value) * 24 * 60 * 60, 2)
            Else:
                nextCell.Formula = nextCell.Formula & "+" & _
                    Round(((Time - .Value) * 24 * 60 * 60) - nextCell.Value, 2)
            End If
'            .Value = ""  'this commented line can be deleted - we'll use the base time
        End If
    End With
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Once the base time is set, it doesn't change.  Then nextCell formula just appends the incremental time difference.
ex. =2+4+1+0+7
Each value is the number of seconds since the last double click.

Comment: I have resolved my problem, you can take a look at question edits and comments for details. Thx for your help.